# How to activate the touch slider for Igx carousel using angular 6+

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular9

How to activate the touch slider for Igx carousel using angular 6+

Actually i need the igx carousel for sliding an image i take a reference from stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-j6q6ad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.html) it's perfectly works in stackblitz, But in our real time environment(Visual Studio Code) the touch slider was not work out, So please kindly help me to activate the touch slider an image and also i attach my code for your reference....

```
    app.componet.html:
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <igx-carousel #carousel>
            <igx-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides;">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img [src]="slide.src">
                </div>
            </igx-slide>
        </igx-carousel>
      </div>
      
    app.component.ts:
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'SampleCarouselThree';
    
      public slides = [
        {
          src: "https://www.infragistics.com/angular-demos/assets/images/carousel/ignite-ui-angular-indigo-design.png"
        },
        {
          src: "https://www.infragistics.com/angular-demos/assets/images/carousel/slider-image-chart.png"
        },
        {
          src: "https://www.infragistics.com/angular-demos/assets/images/carousel/ignite-ui-angular-charts.png"
        }
    ];
    }
    app.component.scss:
    @import '~igniteui-angular/lib/core/styles/themes/index';
    
    .carousel-container{
        width: 70vw;
        height: 80vh;
        margin: 16px auto;
    }
    
    :host ::ng-deep{
    
        .image-container{
            max-width: 85%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    
        .igx-carousel{
            max-width: 100%;
            width: unset;
        }
    
        .igx-nav-dot{
            background: black;
            box-shadow: none;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
        }
    
        .igx-slide{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            max-width: 100%;
            width: unset;
        }
    
        .igx-slide img{
            object-fit: fill;
            max-width: 90%;
        }
    
    }
    app.module.ts:
    
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    
    
    import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
    import { IgxCarouselModule, IgxSliderModule } from "igniteui-angular";
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        IgxCarouselModule,
        IgxSliderModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
    
    style.scss:
    // CSS Reset, comment out if not required or using a different module
    // @import '~minireset.css/minireset';
    @import '~igniteui-angular/lib/core/styles/themes/index';
    @include igx-core();
    @include igx-theme($default-palette, $legacy-support: true);
    
    :root {
        @include css-vars-from-palette($default-palette);
    }
    
    /* autoprefixer grid: on */
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    .sample-wrapper {
        width: inherit;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    .sample-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-animation: fade-in .3s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
        -moz-animation: fade-in .3s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
        animation: fade-in .3s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
    }
    
    .sample-column {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        flex: 1 0 25%;
        align-content: flex-start;
        margin: 16px;
        min-width: 280px;
    }
    
    .sample-title {
        color: #0375be;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
    
    .sample-title .light {
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .sample-description {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #717171;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes color-change-2x {
        0% {
            background: #fdf8f0;
        }
        100% {
            background: #f6e7ec;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes color-change-2x {
        0% {
            background: #fdf8f0;
        }
        100% {
            background: #f6e7ec;
        }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes fade-in {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    
    .headerAlignSyle {
        text-align: right !important;
    }
    
    $green-palette: igx-palette($primary: #09f,$secondary: #72da67, $surface: #333);
    
    .fin-dark-theme {
        @include igx-dark-theme($green-palette);
         background: #333;
    
         ::-moz-placeholder {
             opacity: 1;
         }
     }
    
    .dark-theme {
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        @include igx-dark-theme($green-palette, $legacy-support: true);
    
        .grid-chart-contextmenu-wrapper{
            @include igx-fluent-dark-theme($fluent-excel-palette);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `hammerjs` for gestures

```
npm install hammerjs
```

and after that add `hammerjs' in polyfills

```
// polyfills.ts

import "hammerjs/hammer";
```

Comment: ya i installed the hammer.js and import "hammerjs/hammer"; in polyfills.ts file but it didn't workout still i didn't get the touch slider...

Comment: @SurendranPrabhakaranD what do you mean when you say "touch slider"?

Comment: touch slider means we need to change the picture by clicking the mouse pointer to change the image for previous and next without using the Arrow Mark...